# Docker compose services cannot communicate in WSL2 environment

Tags: python, selenium, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a simple docker compose for python - selenium testing. While everything works in Linux server, when running containers in WSL2 python cannot connect to selenium. Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong, or is there something platform specific I'm missing.

Docker compose:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  selenium:
    image: "selenium/standalone-firefox:4.5.2-20221021"
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
      - "7900:7900"
    shm_size: '2gb'
    container_name: selenium


  python:
    build: "python"
    container_name: python_tests
    depends_on:
      - "selenium"
```

Dockerfile for python:

```
FROM python:3.10
COPY selenium_tests.py ./
COPY requirements.txt ./
ENV NO_PROXY = selenium:4444
RUN ["python3.10", "-m", "pip",  "install", "-r", "requirements.txt"]
CMD ["python3.10", "selenium_tests.py"]
```

Relevant part of python test file

```
print("sleeping so selenium wakes")
sleep(10)
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://selenium:4444/wd/hub', options=webdriver.FirefoxOptions())
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This (once again) was indeed a proxy issue. No proxies started working when I added them to docker-compose.yml AND formatted the no_proxys so that they didn't have port.